# Is there a list usable Monero Faucets?

Tags: tipping

I am new to this forum. 
Just wondering is there a list usable Monero Faucets somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know there are currently no faucets available for Monero. If I recall correctly though, [MoneroDice](https://monerodice.net/) is going to implmenent one in the foreseeable future.

Alternatively, if you want some spare change to play around with, people on IRC will generally give you some (there's a tipbot in #monero). The channel is #monero on [freenode](https://freenode.net/). To join this channel, simply connect to the freenode server in your client and join #monero. If you don't have a client, you can use [this](https://webchat.freenode.net/). Pick a nickname and set the channel to #monero.

Comment: Furthermore, there are options to follow #monero with Slack and Telegram.

Answer (score 7):

There is one Monero faucet left that I know of: http://monerofaucet.info

I found this faucet on http://faucetdump.com

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a monero wallet... you can visit [this faucet site](http://monerofaucet.info/) and get free monero. Just enter your payment address. You can only do it once every hour, but if you get other referrals you can make it even faster!

Comment: That site has a lot of MinerGate and other bytecoin associated stuff on it...... I wouldn't recommend it.